# Interactive map for when and where to go

Tags: weather-and-climate, maps

First, some context: I am planning a very long trip through the Americas by bike. Thus, I need to know what kind of climate I should expect in each country (mostly temperature and rain). I could go and see for every country (that's actually what I've started to do), but I'd rather have a single map displaying all the data I need.

The closest map I've found is from lastminute.com, but I only found it on [this website](https://www.thrillist.com/news/nation/where-to-travel-map-around-world) ([direct link to the video](https://assets3.thrillist.com/v1/image/2710780/video/desktop.webm)). It's close enough, but the video format is not great and the map is not really detailed.

This [risk map](https://www.travelriskmap.com/#/planner/map/newsroom) is really good, and I'd like to find something similar but for the climate, where I could choose the month and have detailed data and weather for each country (or, even better, area).

Does anyone know something like that?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you should probably be made aware that the "closest map you've found" is telling you about *tourist numbers*, not climate.

Comment: Yes I know, but usually tourists tend to follow the weather, so that's a good start.

Comment: The "Americas" are rather big. Any single map will not have enough resolution to useful on a scale for biking distances. There is a lot of local and daily variation.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found something close to what I was looking for: [holiday-weather.com](https://www.holiday-weather.com/country/argentina/). This link is centered on Argentina, but you can move the map around; more importantly, you can select "Weather Average" to get just that on the map.